# Asp.net DetailsView - multiple columns?

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

By default, DetailsView supports 2 columns.  I'd like to add a third column.  Is this possible using DetailsView?  Creating a table within each field doesn't do what I'd like as the third column won't be properly aligned.

I know I can use other controls such as DataList, but having the typed asp:HyperLinkField / asp:CheckBoxField / etc of DetailsView and corresponding properties is extremely convenient.

Does the best of both worlds (the flexibility of DataList and the built-in shorthand objects of DetailsView) exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a custom template & layout, you should use `FormView`, as it will behave and have the same events as the detailsView.

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf1dk77%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
and [Using the FormView's Templates](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-the-formview-s-templates-cs)

Comment: I ended up using DataList but will try FormView next time, thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you think DetailsView supports only two columns.  There's a comprehensive example on MSDN that has multiple columns (fields):

[DetailsView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx)

Comment: I think you're mixing up columns vs. rows - I know I can add X # of rows / fields, but I believe only 2 columns are supported.  If I'm wrong please confirm the syntax, I don't see it in the link you provided

Comment: I don't see anything in the link that says only two columns are supported; in fact, columns aren't even mentioned, just fields.  If you have a row of data, it would seem rather limiting to only be able to display 2 columns/fields from that row.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean by columns?